# How to check if a number can be represented as sum of numbers from a to b?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to check if a number N can be represented as sum of numbers from a to b, where the concatenation of a and b is equal to N?

for eg 429 can be represented as sum of numbers from 4 to 29, and concatenation of 4 and 29  =  429

Answer (score 1):

Solve

$$\frac{b(b+1)-a(a-1)}2=B a+b=N,$$ where $B=10^{\lfloor\log_{10}b\rfloor+1}$.

By eliminating $a$, this reduces to

$$B^2(b(b+1)-2N)-(N-b)(N-b-B)=0$$
or

$$(B^2-1)b^2+2bN-N^2+B(B-1)b+B(1-2B)N=0,$$

which is a family of hyperbolas by the origin, with the additional constraint

$$\frac B{10}\le b<B.$$

Note that after reduction of the conic, a linear transformation with rational coefficients leads to

$$\lambda x^2-\mu y^2=1,$$ where $\lambda,\mu$ are rational, which reminds of the Pell-Fermat equation.

---

**Update:**

The second equation factors as

$$((B+1)b-N-B^2)((B-1)b+N-B(B-1))=B^3(1-B).$$

So for a given $B$, you try all factorizations of $B^2(B-1)$ and solve for $b$ and $N$ until you find integer solutions that fit in the range of $b$.

Comment: can you also explain a little

Comment: @srox: explain what ? Do you understand the initial equation ?